# Paste Excel Table into TinyMCE while Keeping Format

Tags: html, excel, plugins, tinymce

Is there a TinyMCE plugin that allows to paste a table from MS Excel while also keeping the format of that table?

**Partial solution**:
So using the paste plugin, you can paste the Excel table onto Word and then from Word paste it onto TinyMCE, which formats correctly. This is not ideal but better than nothing. Still hoping someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out [the paste plugin](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste). This plugin needs to be configured properly.
have a look [here for the documentation.](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste)

**EDIT:** Example to log the pasted content:

```
    paste_preprocess : function(pl, o) {
        console.log('Object', o);
        console.log('Content:', o.content);
   }
```

Comment: Thariama. Has pasting from Excel worked for you? Using the paste plugin, pasting a table from Word is fine, but I can't configure it to work for Excel.

Comment: hmm, in that case you will have to use the paste_preprocess setting to define an own function in which you have to take care of the format yourself

Comment: But won't one have to work with MS Clipboard somehow? How can my function "anticipate" the formatting from Excel and handle it?

Comment: i am not used to copy from excel, but you can use firebug to log what gets pasted into the editor - maybe there are some special markers which identify that the content came from excel

Comment: is anyone have a luck with excel sheets. MS word works fine. But excel is not working.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that works is if you copy as image in MS Excel and then paste the table as an image.

Answer (score 0):

To Paste Excel data into TinyMCE Editor with formatting,

Please refer: [Paste Excel data into TinyMCE with Formatting](http://non-stop-ext.blogspot.in/2014/05/paste-excel-data-into-tinymce.html)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i m copying the formatted table form the word and paste it into the  tinymce but i m not getting the format same as the word. tinymce losses the format.how to resolve this issue ?